# Pass cmd argument to running process when shutting down windows service

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-services, process-monitor

I am creating a windowservice that starts a process where I pass multiple cmd arguments in the `StartInfo.Arguments`. That works fine as expected.

The problem is that when i stop the windowsservice, I need to tell the running program to shut down gracefully before the windows service stops. Because if I just kill the process the program does not save the collected data. The program that I run is the *Process Monitor* and it accepts the following command `"/terminate"`.

How can I pass the `/terminate` argument before my windows service stops?

Comment: using IDisposable pattern, when calling the windows service onStop, you should call the dispose for all your services! one of this service is responsible for running that Procss command, that process should implement `IDisposable` and make the actions there

Comment: @omriman12 Thanks! I will check it out and get back to you.

Comment: @omriman12 I cant seem to get my head around this. Do you have any links for more information? Code examples.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways you can approach this solution but you can signal the process, and based on what you send with this signal it should execute its 'clean-up' code. Once it's finished, the process that spawned it should be signalled that it finished the cleanup code and can then shutdown. This of course assumes that you wrote the code for both the Window service and the process being spawned.

You can try Named pipes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. In the `OnStop()` method in the service, I needed to create a new instance of the *Process Monitor* and pass the `/Terminate` argument:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.FileName = "\Procmon.exe" ;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/AcceptEula /Terminate";
process.Start();
```

With that it stoppes all the *Process Monitor* instances gracefully.